# Let $w$ denote cube root of unity which is not equal to 1. Then the number of distinct element in the set {$(1+w+w^2+...+w^n)^m : m,n=1,2,3,.. $}

Tags: complex-numbers

I know it follows part cycle mod 3 but I don't understand how to find different element in set, do I have to think of all possible values in the set?

Comment: What do you mean by distinct elements in the set?  The expression you have shown evaluates to one of two complex numbers, depending on which $w$ is chosen.  It is not a set.  If you mean the number of terms in the expanded expression, you can use   $w^3=1$ to reduce everything to $a+bw+cw^2$ so aren't there only three terms?

Comment: This is not my self made statement this question is from Indian Statical Institute's 2008 question paper. And no there are 7 elements according to the answer key, the problem I having is understanding what and how exactly I get those elements.@RossMillikan

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $1+w+w^2=0$, $(1+w)^2=w$.

Another hint for a slightly different approach:
$$
1+w+w^2+\cdots+w^n = \frac{w^{n+1}-1}{w-1}
$$
The powers of $w$ are $w^0=1, w^1=w, w^2, w^3=1, w^4=w, w^5=w^2, \dots$.

Therefore, $1+w+w^2+\cdots+w^n = 1+w, 0, 1, 1+w, 0, 1, \dots$.

Comment: Well I know this but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $1+w+\ldots+w^n\in\{0,1,1+w\}$ and $1+w=-w^2$. Can you finish it off?

Comment: Yeah I guess, I am gonna try.

Comment: I've got {$0,1,w^2,-1,w,-w^2$} but can't seem to find what's missing. There are 7 in answer.

Comment: What's  $(1+w)^5$?